# Validating Mongoose model for predefined values

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a `User` model with an attribute of `role` (type is `String`). I would like users to be saved only when the value of this attribute is either `user`, `provider` or `admin`.

How can I set up such validation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoose has an [`enum`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-enum) validator for string fields:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  ...
  role : { type : String, enum : [ 'user', 'provider', 'admin' ] },
  ...
});
```